# Proof of Nonnegative Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How can I solve this question?[image]

Comment: note that since we can fix $n=1$, this is the same as proving $\det(A_1^tA_1)\ge0$ individually.

Comment: $\det(A + B) \neq \det(A) + \det(B)$!

Comment: @MichaelJoyce ouch.

Comment: Indeed, just consider $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$, $B = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$.  Then $\det(A) = \det(B) = 0$, but $A+B = I_2$ and so $\det(A+B) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\sum_{i=1}^nA_i^tA_i$ is a symmetric real non-negative definite matrix.

Comment: Can you expand that hint a bit more?

Comment: A symmetric real non-negative matrix has a non-negative determinant because its eigenvalues are non-negative.

Comment: Okay I understand the hint, but stil hard to solve it...:(